# I want to sum the salary of each department how can i do it?

Tags: python

```
    list_name=[]
    list_dep=[]
    list_salary=[]
    name1='abdo'
    list_name.append(name1)
    dep1='front_end'
    list_dep.append(dep1)
    salary1=3000
    list_salary.append(salary1)
    
    name2='salm'
    list_name.append(name2)
    dep2='front_end'
    list_dep.append(dep2)
    salary2=5000
    list_salary.append(salary2)
    sum1=0
    for department1 in list_dep:  
      if 'front_end' == department1:
        sum1+= list_salary[department1.index('front_end')]
    print("Front_end: "+str(sum1))
   #I want to collect the price in each section of this program must print 8000 but its print 6000 how to solve this?
```

I want to sum the salary of each department how can i do it
#I hope my question and heal and was clear

Comment: Don't use separate lists like this. Put all the related data together in a dictionary or tuple, and put those in a single list.

Comment: you should do it like barmar said. the answer to why it prints out 6000 instead of 8000 is, `list.index(x)` will always get the first occurence of where x is True. See [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). Your list `list_dep` has twice the same element, your code always picks index of `0`

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to hold the running totals for each department. You can use `defaultdict` to automatically initialize dictionary entries for each department.

```
from collections import defaultdict

total_salaries = defaultdict(int)

for department, salary in zip(list_dep, list_salary):
    total_salaries[department] += salary

print(dict(total_salaries))
```

Comment: you seem professional in python is it possible to to tell me how to become a professional like you though you have a twitter account or the watts numper  will be thankful for you

Comment: Haha, I've never written a python program outside of Stack Overflow answers. In my work I use PHP, JavaScript, and bash.

Comment: I'm just good at learning programming languages. In my career I've used about a dozen different langauges.

Answer (score 0):

the current implementation will make this very hard to maintain and will cause duplication in `list_dep` as you have appended `front_end` twice one with `dep1` and one with `dep2` and the reason you got 6000 because when you ran `list_salary[department1.index('front_end')]` the `department1.index('front_end')` returned index 0 in both times so you added the first index in `list_salary` twice

I recommend changing the structure to use dictionary so it would be like so

```
list_employees = []
name1='abdo'
dep1='front_end'
salary1=3000
list_employees.append({
  "name": name1,
  "dep": dep1,
  "salary": salary1
})

name2='salm'
dep2='front_end'
salary2=5000
list_employees.append({
  "name": name2,
  "dep": dep2,
  "salary": salary2
})
```

now if you want to get the total salaries for a specific salary you can use the following

```
sum1 = 0
for employee in list_employees:  
  if 'front_end' == employee["dep"]:
    sum1 += employee["salary"]
print("Front_end: "+str(sum1))
```

or if you want to get the salaries for all departments then you can do the following

```
list_salaries = {}
for employee in list_employees:  
  if employee["dep"] in list_salaries:
    list_salaries[employee["dep"]] += employee["salary"]
  else:
    list_salaries[employee["dep"]] = employee["salary"]
print(list_salaries)
```